# Accessing JAX-WS webservice from C# issue

Tags: java, c#, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I have to use a SOAP web service in a VPN network (so you couldn't test it), written in Java (**JAX-WS** webservice). 
I don't have access at server side. When i try to call a web method from a C# 4.0 client I get this exception:

```
  The CustomBinding on the ServiceEndpoint with contract 'ServicesSoap' lacks a TransportBindingElement.  Every binding must have at least one binding element that derives from TransportBindingElement.
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding.EnsureInvariants(String contractName)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelFactory.BuildChannelFactory(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, Boolean useActiveAutoClose)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.CreateFactory()
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.OnOpening()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.EnsureOpened()
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1.CreateChannel(EndpointAddress address, Uri via)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannel()
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannelInternal()
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.get_Channel()
   at GatewayClient.Lotto.ServicesSoapClient.GatewayClient.Lotto.ServicesSoap.InfoRequest(InfoRequestRequest request)
   at GatewayClient.Lotto.ServicesSoapClient.InfoRequest(infoDataIn request)
   at GatewayClient.MainWindow.InfoRequestButton_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

This is my app.config:

```
   <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="ServicesSoapPortBinding">
                <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://xxx.yyy/Services"
            binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServicesSoapPortBinding"
            contract="ServiceReference1.ServicesSoap" name="ServicesSoapPort" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue adding **httpTransport** in the **binding** tag, in the app.config:

```
<binding name="ServicesSoapPortBinding">
    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
    <httpTransport/>
</binding>
```

I have to add the service reference within Visual Studio "Service References" feature. Trying to use **svcutil**, I get another different exception.